# Why NA values in subsets after differencing in R?

Tags: r, subset, na

Hello and thanks in advance.  I'm trying to run a unit root test on a subset of series `X` after it has been differenced, `X_diff`

```
X_diff <- diff(X, differences = 1)

urdfTest( subset(X_diff, dat[["Year"]] > 2001 ), lags = 4, type = c("c"), doplot = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:  `'Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object'`

Now I noticed that if I view the entire `X_diff` variable, I get no `NA` values.  However, if I view the subset of `X_diff` variable (code below) I get an `NA` value all the way at the end, and this is true for any year I place into the condition.

```
TBG_diff[which(dat[["Year"]] > 2001)]
```

Why does the `NA` appear and how can I run the subset of the differenced series without getting the `NA` error?

Comment: What is the output of `traceback()`?

Comment: Do you still have the problem after trying: `X_diff <- X_diff[!which(is.na(X_diff))]` ?

Comment: @Frank did you mean x_diff[!is.na(x_diff)] ? You don't need the `which` here. `-which(..)` would also have worked but `!which(...)` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.

@ashkan, when i try to run the unit-root test and then use traceback() I get this:  

3: stop("\nNAs in y.\n")
2: ur.df(x, type = Type, lags = lags)
1: urdfTest(subset(TBG_diff, dat[["Year"]] > 2001), lags = 4, type = c("ct"), 
       doplot = TRUE)

Comment: @Frank yes I do still unfortunately

Comment: Mentioning `urdfTest` is confusing here, as that comes from some package that you haven't mentioned. Can you construct a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (different Frank here, by the way.)

Comment: @Vincent yes, you're right, the `which` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem is that you have differenced, so, one end of the differences is looking for a year that doesn't exist (either the year before the first year you have data for, or the year after the last year you have data for).

The solution would be to difference for a set that is one year shorter than your actual set of years

EDIT

Thinking about it some more, I think you should subset before you difference rather than the other way around. Something like

```
X_2001 <- subset(X, dat[["Year"]] > 2001)
urdfTest(X_2001, MORE CODE HERE)
```

Comment: This answer clearly is about the logic of differencing time series, and would apply to many implementations, rather than the particulars of implementation in R. It's not clear to me why this was considered off topic on CV.

Comment: I agree that the question was asked in that way but the actual issue seems to be more one of statistical analysis (in the sense of thinking about what effect the difference transformation will have). Perhaps I am mistaken; it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Or it could be me that's mistaken. Also not a first time. :-)

Comment: @PeterFlom, thanks for the advice.  I'm trying to attempt it but I can't seem to get it right.  Do you have the code?  I'm attempting:

X_diff <- diff( subset( date[["X"]], dat[["Year"]] < 2013), differences = 1)

Comment: @PeterFlom that worked! thank you very much.  Do you happen to know the technical reason why that occurs?  I'm new to R but not to stat programs like SPSS and STATA.

Comment: I don't really know. I would probably have tried what you did first